# Grouping and summing an embedded array by month

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I have the following schema :

```
_id 
dates : 
    date :
       year
       month
       day
other unrelated fields
```

I already grouped each _id such that dates contain multiple date objects (which contain the year, month, day). I want to now group each date object by year and month such that I get the count of the number of dates corresponding to the year and month. For example, if I have the following document :

```
_id : 124567789554
dates : 
    date : 
        year : 2018
        month : 9
        day : 1
    date : 
        year : 2018
        month : 9
        day : 2
    date : 
        year : 2018
        month : 9
        day : 3
    date : 
        year : 2018
        month : 10
        day : 1
```

The output that I want is :

```
_id : 124567789554
dates : 
    date : 
        year : 2018
        month : 9
        count : 3
    date : 
        year : 2018
        month : 10
        count : 1
```

How can I go about doing this?

Edit : For some additional context, I first have to group by a personId. Initially the schema looks like this :

```
_Id (automatically generated by mongoDB)
personId 
date
```

There are multiple rows with the same personId, corresponding to a date. I have to first group such that _Id = personId, and aggregate the dates together. How can I do both at the same time? My current query:

```
{
  _id: "$personId",
  dates: {
    $addToSet: "$date"
  },
  other unrelated fields
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$group` to group by person id, month and year and count the no of matches followed by `$group` to collect all the dates with year and month and count for each person id.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"personId":"$personId","year":"$date.year","month":"$date.month"},
    "count":{"$sum":1}
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$_id.personId",
    "dates":{"$push":{"year":"$_id.year","month":"$_id.month","count":"$count"}}
  }}
])
```

Comment: This solution works, thanks! How can I access the object inside the dates array though? I'm trying to $match the count to create a new boolean field that returns true if any of the counts for any month is greater than 5.

Comment: Yw. Add `"countgt5":{"$cond":[{"$gt":["$count",5]},true,false]}` after count field in $push.

Comment: This adds the true/false field to EACH count of the year/month, but I want this field to return true/false if ANY of the year/months have a count greater than 5 (so only one of this field for each document, rather than one field for each year/month count)

Comment: ah. Missed that part. Add the following stage after $group stage. `{"$addFields":{"countgt5":{"$gt":[{"$size":{"$filter":{"input":"$dates","cond":{"$gt":["$$this.count",5]}}}},0]}}}`

Comment: You're a god. Thanks a lot! I'm completely new to NoSQL queries and I'm definitely learning a lot here.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your field in [BSON Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date) format, easily achievable by using [group aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

A very similar code example from Mongo Document:

```
db.sales.aggregate(
   [
      {
        $group : {
           _id : { month: { $month: "$date" }, day: { $dayOfMonth: "$date" }, year: { $year: "$date" } },
           totalPrice: { $sum: { $multiply: [ "$price", "$quantity" ] } },
           averageQuantity: { $avg: "$quantity" },
           count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      }
   ]
)
```

Result:

```
{ "_id" : { "month" : 3, "day" : 15, "year" : 2014 }, "totalPrice" : 50, "averageQuantity" : 10, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "month" : 4, "day" : 4, "year" : 2014 }, "totalPrice" : 200, "averageQuantity" : 15, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "month" : 3, "day" : 1, "year" : 2014 }, "totalPrice" : 40, "averageQuantity" : 1.5, "count" : 2 }
```

Comment: I think mine is a little different because I first have to group by personId. The beginning schema looks like this : _id, personId, date, ...  Since there are multiple dates corresponding to one person there are multiple rows of personId with a corresponding date.